# convert grayscale image to false colors / pseudo colors in c# or c++

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing, colors

Hi what I'm trying to do is converting a grayscale image (`Bitmap`) to false colors / pseudo colors using C# or C++.

Doing research I just found two unfinished answers for this e.g. http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4132 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20468006/2798895

What pseudo colors are can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color#Pseudocolor

Any suggestions how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to do a table-based transformation on the values to get colors.

For a simple example, let's assume a simple two-color fade from blue at the cold end (which I'll assume is an intensity of 0) to red at the hot end (which I'll assume is an intensity of 256).

For this, we might write a conversion table something like this:

```
struct triplet {
    char r, g, b;
};

static const int count = 256;

std::vector<triplet> table;

for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
    table.push_back({i, 0, count-i});
```

With this built, we can convert an input from an intensity to a pseudo-color fairly easily:

```
pseudocolor = table[intensity];
```

If you want a gradient that's more complex, such as flowing from blue to green to yellow to red, you probably want to start with a color model like HLS or HSV, then doing a conversion from that color model to RGB to generate your color values. This makes it much easier to compute values that have about the same level of saturation and brightness while moving though a range of shades.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way I'd do it is to convert the image to grayscale paletted format, and then just give it a hue-changing palette. I got toolsets for all of those (and have, in fact, done it). I'll see if I can find the relevant code.

To make the grayscale paletted image, well, you should be able to [get the original image's pixels out somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49859493/395685), and if they're already gray, any of the R/G/B components will do. Store those in a byte array and bake a paletted image out of it. The easiest way to do this is with the `Image.LockBits` function, which gives direct access to the array backing an image. Here's my tool function for it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a bitmap based on data, width, height, stride and pixel format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceData">Byte array of raw source data</param>
/// <param name="width">Width of the image</param>
/// <param name="height">Height of the image</param>
/// <param name="stride">Scanline length inside the data</param>
/// <param name="pixelFormat">Pixel format</param>
/// <param name="palette">Color palette</param>
/// <param name="defaultColor">Default color to fill in on the palette if the given colors don't fully fill it.</param>
/// <returns>The new image</returns>
public static Bitmap BuildImage(Byte[] sourceData, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, PixelFormat pixelFormat, Color[] palette, Color? defaultColor)
{
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
    BitmapData targetData = newImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, newImage.PixelFormat);
    Int32 newDataWidth = ((Image.GetPixelFormatSize(pixelFormat) * width) + 7) / 8;
    // Compensate for possible negative stride on BMP format.
    Boolean isFlipped = targetData.Stride < 0;
    Int32 targetStride = Math.Abs(targetData.Stride);
    Int64 scan0 = targetData.Scan0.ToInt64();
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
        Marshal.Copy(sourceData, y * stride, new IntPtr(scan0 + y * targetStride), newDataWidth);
    newImage.UnlockBits(targetData);
    // Fix negative stride on BMP format.
    if (isFlipped)
        newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
    // For indexed images, set the palette.
    if ((pixelFormat & PixelFormat.Indexed) != 0 && palette != null)
    {
        ColorPalette pal = newImage.Palette;
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < pal.Entries.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < palette.Length)
                pal.Entries[i] = palette[i];
            else if (defaultColor.HasValue)
                pal.Entries[i] = defaultColor.Value;
            else
                break;
        }
        newImage.Palette = pal;
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Now, for that to get nice colours, you of course need a palette. For this, I use Rich Newman's HSLColor class:

https://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/hslcolor-class/

Note that I made a small adaption to this code, and made the private const "scale" into a public static "SCALE" instead to easily access it for my operations.

```
/// <summary>
/// Generates a colour palette of the given bits per pixel containing a hue rotation of the given range.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bpp">Bits per pixel of the image the palette is for.</param>
/// <param name="blackOnZero">Replace the first colour on the palette with black.</param>
/// <param name="addTransparentZero">Make the first colour on the palette transparent.</param>
/// <param name="reverseGenerated">Reverse the generated range. This happens after the generating, and before the operations on the first index/</param>
/// <param name="startHue">Start hue range. Value from 0 to 240.</param>
/// <param name="endHue">End hue range. Value from 0 to 240. Must be higher then startHue.</param>
/// <param name="inclusiveEnd">True to include the end hue in the palette. If you generate a full hue range, this can be set to False to avoid getting a duplicate red colour on it.</param>
/// <returns>The generated palette, as array of System.Drawing.Color objects.</returns>
public static Color[] GenerateRainbowPalette(Int32 bpp, Boolean blackOnZero, Boolean addTransparentZero, Boolean reverseGenerated, Int32 startHue, Int32 endHue, Boolean inclusiveEnd)
{
    Int32 colors = 1 << bpp;
    Color[] pal = new Color[colors];
    Double step = (Double)(endHue - startHue) / (inclusiveEnd ? colors - 1 : colors);
    Double start = startHue;
    Double satValue = ColorHSL.SCALE;
    Double lumValue = 0.5 * ColorHSL.SCALE;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < colors; i++)
    {
        Double curStep =  start + step * i;
        pal[i] = new ColorHSL(curStep, satValue, lumValue);
    }
    if (reverseGenerated)
    {
        Color[] entries = pal.Reverse().ToArray();
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < pal.Length; i++)
            pal[i] = entries[i];
    }
    if (blackOnZero)
        pal[0] = Color.Black;
    // make color 0 transparent
    if (addTransparentZero)
        pal[0] = Color.FromArgb(0, pal[0]);
    return pal;
}
```

A full hue rotation would go from red to yellow to cyan to green to blue to purple and back to red. To get a nice effect on false colours, though, you don't want the highest values to resemble the lowest ones, so it's better to go from blue to red. This means, limiting the generated range, and reversing the final palette, which is why I added those options in the function.

The final call for the blue-to-red rainbow was this:

```
Color[] heightmap = PaletteUtils.GenerateRainbowPalette(8, false, false, true, 0, 160, true);
```

The result, as applied on a terrain height map from a game:

[image: Height map in hue colours]