# c# RGB Values from Bitmap Data

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am new in working with Bitmap and using  16 bits per pixel `Format16bppRgb555`;

I want to Extract RGB Values from Bitmap Data. Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BitmapRGBValues();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


 static unsafe void BitmapRGBValues()
    {

        Bitmap cur = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
        //Capture Screen
        var screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(cur))
        {
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(screenBounds.X, screenBounds.Y, 0, 0, screenBounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }

        var curBitmapData = cur.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, cur.Width, cur.Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);


        try
        {
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)curBitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();

            for (int y = 0; y < cur.Height; ++y)
            {
                ulong* curRow = (ulong*)(scan0 + curBitmapData.Stride * y);

                for (int x = 0; x < curBitmapData.Stride / 8; ++x)
                {

                    ulong pixel = curRow[x];

                    //How to get RGB Values  from pixel;







                }

            }


        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cur.UnlockBits(curBitmapData);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Look up bit operations in c#!

Comment: The blocks in a 16bpp image are UInt16 (ushort), not ulong. Once you got that, bit-shift the values out. That aside... what do you mean with "extract", here? Your return type is `void`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LockBits can actually *convert* your image to a desired pixel format, meaning no further conversion should be needed. Just lock the image as `Format32bppArgb` and you can simply take your colour values from single bytes.

```
BitmapData curBitmapData = cur.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, cur.Width, cur.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Int32 stride = curBitmapData.Stride;
Byte[] data = new Byte[stride * cur.Height];
Marshal.Copy(curBitmapData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
cur.UnlockBits(curBitmapData);
```

With this code, you end up with the byte array `data`, which is filled with your image data in ARGB format, meaning the colour component bytes will be in there in the order [B, G, R, A]. Note that the `stride` is the amount of bytes to skip to get to a next line on the image, and since this is *not* always equal to "width * bytes per pixel", it should always be taken into account.

Now you got that, you can do whatever you want with it...

```
Int32 curRowOffs = 0;
for (Int32 y = 0; y < cur.Height; y++)
{
    // Set offset to start of current row
    Int32 curOffs = curRowOffs;
    for (Int32 x = 0; x < cur.Width; x++)
    {
        // ARGB = bytes [B,G,R,A]
        Byte b = data[curOffs];
        Byte g = data[curOffs + 1];
        Byte r = data[curOffs + 2];
        Byte a = data[curOffs + 3];
        Color col = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

        // Do whatever you want with your colour here
        // ...

        // Increase offset to next colour
        curOffs += 4;
    }
    // Increase row offset
    curRowOffs += stride;
}
```

You can even edit the bytes, and then [build a new image from them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967594/395685) if you want.

Comment: How can the order be like  [B, G, R, A] and not [A, R, G, B]..... according to documentation {The format also defines the order of the color components within a single pixel of data} ..... The format in PixelFormat is ARGB so what i am asking why did you reverse to BGRA???????

Comment: @user1477332 Look up the concept of "endianness". PC CPUs are little-endian, meaning bytes are stored in reverse order. So a byte sequence "AA BB CC DD", interpreted as little-endian `UInt32`, becomes the _value_ 0xDDCCBBAA. Since the `System.Drawing` classes use data that way, and an ARGB colour refers to the colour as `UInt32`, not as byte array, you need to reverse that order to handle the colours as bare bytes.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for clarification, it helped me alot