# Image color recognition, inverted color detection

Tags: java, c#, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-recognition

I'm working on a image manipulation. I have a problem I'm dealing with it, I didn't get any results. I need an algorithm to detect inverted colors.

As in the example photo below, I need to find and fix the inverted colors:

[image]

Currently I'm trying to find solution with using Java and C# .

I get the best closest result with this method. I convert the image to invert and two image compare with pixel-by-pixel. 70% success.

```
    public static Color getTrueColor(this Color t, Color m)
    {
        int[] a = { t.R, t.G, t.B };
        int[] b = { m.R, m.G, m.B };

        int x = (int)a.Average();
        int y = (int)b.Average();

        return  x < y ? m : t;

    }
```

Thanks in advance for every help and suggestion.

Comment: Hi, this is a rather broad and complex question. Do you have any restrictions? Environmental parameters? Some code to show?

Comment: It is advised to edit your attempt at a solution into your post.

Comment: @Stefan Unfortunately no

Comment: Hmm... that's to bad..... Another thing; I don't think this image is fully inverted.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, This image is partially inverted. That is main proplem.

Comment: ... wow... that's a hard nut to crack.... it is possible, but it is gonna take a lot of effort. You could use some color distribution correlation, but that would fail very quickly if multiple "colors" are inverted. And, besides, you will need a valid test set. If you now nothing about the image (people in it, always correctly orrientated, always a sky in it etc.) it's going to be really difficult....

Comment: @Uysal Would you consider using artifical inteligence?

Comment: Just curious: Where did these partially inverted image come from?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski May be, but which AI can solve this problem?

Comment: @hkchengrex  It was obtained with a thermal image processing algorithm.

Comment: I'd say to check for minimal threshold differences between inverted neighbouring pixels to make regions suspected of being inverted... but this is saved as jpeg. It'd be a lot less complicated if it weren't fuzzed up with fades and compression artifacts. I posted an algo for blob detection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282882/395685); if you have a non-blurred version, the threshold function to use on it should just be comparing pixels with their inverted neighbour.