# Detect contour and associated pixels

Tags: c#, image-processing, pixel, contour

I have a 2D image, each pixel can have one of the 4 values: 1 (red), 2 (gray blue), 3 (yellow) and 4 (orange).

[image]

I want to detect the contour of this image and associated pixels like this:

[image]

I actually use C# and have very limited access to popular library like openCV, etc. Could you provide me some hints to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: It's not clear what you call *contour* (what result is expected? numbers? array of points? polygone?). It looks like you want to estimate continous area of same color, see [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

Comment: Hi Sinatr, I want, for the above example, to obtain a list of points (or pixels number) within each region (red, yellow, gray blue, orange) and the coordinate which allows to define the contour polygon.

Comment: Contours/regions are some work to get, but just a list of the pixels of each colour? That seems pretty trivial to me. As for region detect, there's [a question I answered on that subject here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282882/395685), so you may want to check that out.